# How can I make HTTP POST and HTTP GET requests in json format to a server from Excel Addin using c#?

Tags: c#, json, excel, rest, excel-addins

I am having trouble regarding the following problem: I want to send a JSON file with HTTP POST from my Excel-Addin written in c# to my web server, and then by using HTTP-GET get the response from the server also in JSON format. I am using Visual Studio 2015. Can you tell me if you have any ideas how could I do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: HTTP POST and GET both have a `request -> response` structure, so it is slightly confusing when you say _"using HTTP GET to get the response"_ Please describe the expectations for your use case a little bit more.  For example what are you posting and what do you expect in response.